# Recursive function with type script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, recursion, promise

I'm playing around with promises and I'm having trouble with an asynchronous recursive promise.

The scenario is that i need to check for token validation inside a function and if the token expires i need to call the function again.
Below is the code i've done so far:

```
module.exports={
 frstFun:()=>{...
 },
 secondFun:(param)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  request({
   url:url+'myapi',
   qs:{q:param,acc_token:token},
   method:'GET',
   },function(err,response,body){
    if(error){
    //here i need to call secondFun() method..
    }
    });
  })
  }

};
```

I tried calling this.secondFun() but it's giving error secondFun() is not a method.

Comment: For that kind of thing, maybe observables are way to go instead retrywhen perhaps https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a recursive retry is the best way to do this, but you could pull the function definition out of the `exports` object:

```
let secondFun = (param) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: url + 'myapi',
            qs: { q: param, acc_token: token },
            method: 'GET',
        }, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                // secondFun(...)
            }
        });
    })
};

module.exports = {
    frstFun: () => { ... },
    secondFun: secondFun 
};
```